# RewriteCond - rewrite query if it contains "bar" and "foo"

Tags: mod-rewrite

This rule will rewrite the query if it contains "foo" anywhere in the string.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)foo(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1qux%2 [R=301,L]
```

What should be added to make it rewrite "foo" only if the string contains "bar" somewhere before "foo". A real-life example would be 
/bar?a=x&foo=y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is more a question about RegEx (regular expressions), actually.

You would need to change your rewrite condition to the following to also match for `bar` somewhere before `foo` in the same query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)bar(.*)foo(.*)$
```

Comment: Turns out the condition has to be in the rule.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)bar(.*)$ $1?%1qux%2 [R=301,L]